# GitHub Pull Request to a new Upstream Branch

Tags: git, github

My workflow: I have a fork (origin) of a remote project (upstream). I have created a branch, topic/TICKET. I want to create a pull request of my origin branch to the upstream project in a same-named, brand new "topic/TICKET" branch. In other words, I don't want my pull request toward the master branch or any existing branch.

When using BitBucket I have this option. When I create my PR, I select my origin branch and then the remote branch selection allows "Create new branch (topic/TICKET)".

In GitHub I don't appear to have this option. I can type in the new branch name; but then the option to continue greys out until I select a valid, existing branch upstream.

The annoying work-around is creating the branches upstream before I perform the PR; but it requires asking someone who can commit upstream -- it seems to me like there must be an easier way to do this.

So, is there any way with GitHub to create a pull request to create a new upstream branch, or is this just a known limitation?

Comment: over 10 years later, Github still does not provide this functionality 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do that on Github. And also think is okay like that, because you shouldn't be able to "create" a new branch on a project you don't necessarily have push access.
Even if you **do** have push access to the upstream project i don't see it as a clean workflow.

Comment: Yeah but you wouldn't be creating a new branch, you'd be creating a "request" for a new branch that would have to be reviewed and accepted. The branch wouldn't exist until someone with the privileges to create the branch gives it the okay.

Comment: GitHub Actions allows to trigger workflows on issue creation / updates. One could build a manual approval flow, where a person proposes a branch to be pushed, somebody else approves it, and then GHA pushes it.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying a similar thing, and the only solution I got is to have an user with push permission to *upstream*.

That way you could do a first push to *upstream*. Right after that, you also do a push to *origin*; and afterwards you can make your pull requests from branch to branch as you wish in first place.

Just be careful when you create the pull request, because the default selected branch for *upstream* is always "master"

Comment: Yeah unfortunately giving them permission is what I'm trying to get away from. Just annoying BitBucket supports this sort of workflow whereas GitHub does not. Ahh well, I've created a tool so they can create the branches themselves to create pull requests against. It gets the job done.

Comment: Well, you don't have to give them permission, just create yourself the branch they need. But anyway, your tool gets the job done ;-)

Comment: @AndrewKandels can you share that tool ? I like to create ```gh-pages``` branch for projects I love. I first fork and create the ```gh-pages``` branch in my repo. I add files and test it using my own fork. Once, they are good enough, I ideally want to send a pull-request where original upstream repo don't have ```gh-pages``` branch.  I have to ask the owner to create an emtpy branch ```gh-pages``` for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I wanted to create a branch from a particular PR is that , in Github go to the particular PR , on the right hand side , you will have SHA , beside that there will be <> symbol , which says "View the repository at this point in history , if you click on that , you will be redirected to the repo when that PR was merged . From there you can create a new branch .