# Can I create pull request with a new branch from fork

Tags: git, github

I forked "**test**" repo.
Then I created a new branch "**feature**" in my fork.
How can I create "**feature**" branch in **"test"** repo?
When I'm creating a pull request I can merge changes from my branch with existing branches, but there is no way to create a new branch.
[image]
Is it possible to create a branch there without asking "**test**" repo owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because there is no way to merge to non-existing branch. You must first create a new branch.

[GitHub Pull Request to a new Upstream Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796370/github-pull-request-to-a-new-upstream-branch)